# operation time out error

Tags: asp.net-2.0

operation time out error while sending files as attachment with size more than 2mb with e-mail(using SMTP client) in asp.net2.0

Comment: what is it that you need to know then? there is no question here - just a statement - anything???

Comment: @PaulStack. Thought i'd take a guess. :)

Comment: i just didnt know where to start lol

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you could provide more context/info with your question, but nonetheless i will take a guess - i'm assuming you want to know "why" it's timing out, and how to resolve it.

Well it's simple, the SMTP transaction has a timeout value in ASP.NET (like most things), and you will need to change it to satisfy your needs.

You need to set the Timeout property on the SMTP object to a higher value.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout.aspx)

The property is in milliseconds (default value is 100 seconds).

You will also need to increase the ASP.NET MaxRequestSize in the web.config.